# Jquery tooltip is not disappearing on click of item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using `jquery-1.9.1.js` and UI `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js`. When I mouse over on any form element it shows tooltip and disappear on mouse out. but I want to vanish that toolip on click event of that item, because in my current scenario it shows tooltip for button and it persist even after button click. hence it see multiple tooltips on the page. I need to hide them immediately after click.(Below is screen shot).

[image]

I used below code but does not work for me

```
 $(document).click(function() {
       $(this).tooltip( "option", "hide", { effect: "explode", duration: 500 } );
        });
```

How to resolve this pls help.

**EDIT**

I am using update panel. will that create problem?

Answer (score 9):

According to the jQueryUI documentation, your code only changes how it closes.  What you want is `close` http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-close.

However you might have to change your code a bit to make it work. Judging by your code you use delegation (allowing something else to make the tool tip for your item), instead of applying it directly to your item.  According to the documentation close does not work on delegated tooltips.

You'll want something similar to

```
$('.editButtons').tooltip().click(function() {
    $('.editButtons').tooltip( "close");
})
```

Comment: Since you provided no other information, this is only a general guideline.  If your buttons don't have the class `editButtons` it won't work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/aeWvK/ for help

Comment: I used `$(docuement).tooltip( "close");`

Comment: I said that wouldn't work in my answer.  `document` has no tooltips it receives them through delegation.  You have to specifically make them on your item(s) by selecting them.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is applying to individual selectors. But i need it to apply it globally so that any element having tooltip; once clicked its tooltip should disappear. Please suggest.

Comment: So it needs to close all open tooltips or just the related one?

Comment: Changed answer to close all opened tooltips.

Comment: Is it for all opened tooltips in the docuement?

Comment: Yes it is for all opened tooltips

Comment: instead of `$('.editButtons').tooltip( "close");` I used  `$(this).tooltip("close");`

Answer (score 5):

Ugly hack for closing delegated tooltip (last one opened)

```
$('div[id^="ui-tooltip-"]:last').remove();
```

Comment: In my case I used `$('div[class^="ui-tooltip"]').remove();` if certain DOM exists/not exists.

Comment: Good hack guys @KAZ-to-USA

Answer (score 3):

I took a slightly different approach while using jq 1.12 by hiding all the ui-tooltips when showing the new one. This is tested in Chrome and IE 11 and IE 11(ie8 emulation via http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8")

```
$.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            $(".ui-tooltip").fadeOut(); /* tooltip genocide */
            return $(this).prop('title');
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            delay: 750
        }
    }
});
```

hth

Comment: Still works great 2/15/2024 jquery 3.6.0 jqueryui 1.13.2

Answer (score 2):

May be a dirty hack but can't you just hide the tooltip element it self by selecting it using "ui-tooltip" which is the class applied to the tooltip container.

```
$('body').on("click","element_selector",function(event){
$('.ui-tooltip').hide();
});
```

You should replace "element_selector" by an appropriate selector for your elements.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but I ran into the same problem and used the following way to solve it.

Let's say you used this to initiate the tooltips:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

The following fades out the tooltip after a click. After fading it removes it from the DOM (otherwise you might end up with lots of hidden tooltips).

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').click(function() {
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I had to rewrite it a bit: `$("[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);

  $(".tooltip").fadeOut("fast", function () {
   $this.blur();
  });
 });` else the tooltip will never come back.

Comment: @Roland I have used blur eventhough am not getting the tooltip again .

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(this).tooltip( "option", "hide", { effect: "explode", duration: 500 } ).off("focusin focusout");
});
```

Comment: This auto-hides the tooltip after some time. I think that is what the questioner doesn't want. It should close immediate on clicking on it as he wrote.